# Spring CRUD - update with @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, crud

I have an update method in my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = Constants.UPDATE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateProduct(@ModelAttribute("productModel") ProductModel productModel) {
    productService.updateProduct(productModel);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/showProducts");

    return modelAndView;

}
```

The problem is when I'm doing an update in the form, all of the fields has to be submitted, if I leave a field empty - I get an error - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. So what would be the best way to make it possible to update only a single column without getting this error? My ProductModel is rather simple I have productName, description and price and my query in the DAO is:

```
String sql = "UPDATE PRODUCT SET description=?, productName=?, price=? WHERE id=?";
```

Comment: i dont't get it. does the updateProduct method get called? no? so you get a "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"? could you please add your ProductModel source code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to read all the product fields from the database before updating, overwrite the ones received from the form, and then update all the fields.